# matplotlib: Avoiding image overlapping with plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to add a figure to my plot using the current code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(Date,Flowday, linewidth=2)
plt.grid()
plt.title('Flow last day [Liter]')
plt.setp(plt.xticks()[1], rotation=30, ha='right')
plt.tight_layout()
image = plt.imread('Logopops.png')
ax = plt.axes([0.6, 0.7, 0.2, 0.2], frameon=True) # [left bottom,...]
ax.imshow(image)
ax.axis('off')
```

The code runs well, but the image ends up overlapping with my plot(like a stamp). Is there any way to avoid this and make it act like Transparent selection in paint ?

Comment: If you want the logo to be faded, set it's `alpha` to a low value, if you want the plot to overlap the logo set the zorder of the second axes to be less than that of the first.

Comment: I have tried to use zoder, but according to the documentation zorder does not work for images :/

Comment: Can you point me to where the docs say that because I am pretty sure it is not true.

Comment: I cant seem to find it , so you might be right. Turned out I could "shake" away the image so it turned out to be less of a problem than expected :), but ty for the help its much appreciated

Comment: There is an an issue with layering image - line - image and then rasterizing just the images as part of a vector output as for size reasons the default behavior is to rasterize all of the artists to be rastered into a single image that goes behind all of the vector elements (so your order is image-image-line), but that is now configurable.  You should answer your own question if you found a solution.